# Call to a member function get() when calling a doctrine 2 entity form the service locator

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am new to Doctrine 2 and ZF2.

**My problem:** I go to the route `myPage/bnk` that instantiates the class `BnkController` and the method `indexAction` if I try to access the `getEntityManager` method **from there it all works**.

Now when I instantiate the class `DataManager` in the method `indexAction` and then I try to call the `getEntityManager` method inside the class `DataManager` I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object`  which I dont understand why is happening if it is all working in the `BnkController`

Why I am getting this error when I try to get the doctrine `EntityManager` from the `getServiceLocator` inside the class `DataManager`?

```
class BnkController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        public function indexAction ()
        {
            $this->uploadCSVAction( "data/bnk.csv" );
        }

        public function uploadCSVAction ( $fileName )
        {
            $parseCSV = new CsvParser();
            $dataManager = new DataManager();

            // Transforms CSV into Array
            $CSVData = $parseCSV->parseCSV( $fileName );

            // Makes sure that we are only using the right transactions and no overlap is happening
            $CSVData = $dataManager->validateTransactions($CSVData,$parseCSV);

            $dataManager->saveCSVDataToDB( $CSVData );

        }

        /**
         * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
         */
        protected function getEntityManager ()
        {
            /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $objectManager */
            $objectManager = $this
                ->getServiceLocator()
                ->get( 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' );

            return $objectManager;
        }
```

DataManager

```
<?php

namespace Bnk\Controller;

/**
 * Class DataManager
 *
 * @package Bnk\Controller
 */
class DataManager {

    /**
     * @return \Bnk\Repository\Transaction
     */
    protected function getTransactionRepository ()
    {
        /** @var \Bnk\Repository\Transaction $repository */
        $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository( 'Bnk\Entity\Transaction' );

        return $repository;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected function getEntityManager ()
    {
        /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $objectManager */
        $objectManager = $this
            ->getServiceLocator()
            ->get( 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' );

        return $objectManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the `DataManager` class.

Comment: Thanks, I've cut it down to what *I believe* is the relevant bits. Feel free to revert it but I think it makes what your asking clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why I am getting this error when I try to get the doctrine EntityManager from the getServiceLocator inside the class DataManager

The `DataManager` has no knowledge of the service locator or the entity manager. Why? because you created it using the `new` operator.

```
$dataManager = new DataManager(); // nothing injected or set
```

You need to ensure you are *injecting your dependencies* using factories and then requesting them via the service locator.

Update the controller to fetch your service

```
$dataManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyModule\Service\DataManager');
```

Create a new factory to inject the **EntityManager** (not the service locator)

```
namespace MyModule\Factory;

use MyModule\Service\DataManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class DataManagerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new DataManager(
            $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        );
    }
}
```

Register you factory with the service manager

```
// MyModule\Module.php
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Service\DataManager'
                => 'MyModule\Factory\DataManagerFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

Lastly, give `DataManager` a constructor, so you can inject the `EntityManager`

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class DataManager
{

    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    protected function getEntityManager ()
    {
      return $this->objectManager;
    }

}
```